# Numpy Vectorization And Speedup

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I found was a small code snippet that used to be a double for loop and I managed to bring it to a single for loop with vectorization. Having dones this resulted in a drastic time improvement so I was wondering if it is possible to get rid of the second for loop here via vectorization as well and if it would improve the performance.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
nlin, npix = 478, 480
bb = np.random.rand(nlin,npix)
slope = -8
fac = 4
offset= 0
barray = np.zeros([2,2259]);

timex = timer()
for y in range(nlin):
    for x in range(npix):
        ling=(np.ceil((x-y/slope)*fac)+1-offset).astype(np.int);
        barray[0,ling] +=1;
        barray[1,ling] +=bb[y,x];
newVar = np.copy(barray)
print(timer() - timex)
```

So the ling can be taken out of the loops by creating the following matrix

```
lingMat = (np.ceil((np.vstack(npixrange)-nlinrange/slope)*fac)+1-offset).astype(np.int);
```

which satisfies lingMat[x,y] = "ling in the for loop at x and y". And this gives a first step of the vectorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of vectorization, you could potentially use something based on [np.add.at](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
def yaco_addat(bb,slope,fac,offset):
    barray = np.zeros((2,2259),dtype=np.float64)
    nlin_range = np.arange(nlin)
    npix_range = np.arange(npix)
    ling_mat = (np.ceil((npix_range-nlin_range[:,None]/slope)*fac)+1-offset).astype(np.int)  
    np.add.at(barray[0,:],ling_mat,1)
    np.add.at(barray[1,:],ling_mat,bb) 
    return barray
```

However, I would suggest you to optimize this directly with [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), using `@jit` decorator with option `nopython=True`, which gives you:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

nlin, npix = 478, 480
bb = np.random.rand(nlin,npix)
slope = -8
fac = 4
offset= 0

def yaco_plain(bb,slope,fac,offset):
    barray = np.zeros((2,2259),dtype=np.float64)
    for y in range(nlin):
        for x in range(npix):
            ling=(np.ceil((x-y/slope)*fac)+1-offset).astype(np.int)
            barray[0,ling] += 1
            barray[1,ling] += bb[y,x]
    return barray

@jit(nopython=True)
def yaco_numba(bb,slope,fac,offset):
    barray = np.zeros((2,2259),dtype=np.float64)
    for y in range(nlin):
        for x in range(npix):
            ling = int((np.ceil((x-y/slope)*fac)+1-offset))
            barray[0,ling] += 1
            barray[1,ling] += bb[y,x]    
    return barray
```

Let's check the outputs

```
np.allclose(yaco_plain(bb,slope,fac,offset),yaco_addat(bb,slope,fac,offset))
>>> True
np.allclose(yaco_plain(bb,slope,fac,offset),yaco_jit(bb,slope,fac,offset))
>>> True
```

and now time these

```
%timeit yaco_plain(bb,slope,fac,offset)
>>> 648 ms ± 4.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit yaco_addat(bb,slope,fac,offset)
>>> 27.2 ms ± 92.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit yaco_jit(bb,slope,fac,offset)
>>> 505 µs ± 995 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

resulting in an optimized function that is way quicker than the initial 2 loops version and `53x` faster than the `np.add.at` one. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Yacola, I am really sorry. It turns out that the first optimization I tried was wrong and that the outputs weren't the same. I have made some progress but can not vectorize the very last line of code. I will edit the code to reflect the original problem.

Comment: There it is now.

Comment: What is numba exactly? And thank you for taking the time.

Comment: My answer said it all.